# Convert UTC time to Local time in springboot

Tags: spring-boot

I have a String time="12:00,14:00,16:00". And I have a timeZone value UTC+05:00 or UTC+07:00 can be anything I need a springboot code that can convert the 12:00 to local. I have already tried zoneddatetime and zoneId. However it needs datetime when I only have time. The parameters cannot be changed. How should I do it?
Note: I cannot change the format of either the values I get or the output i.e the time must be in HH:mm format only

Used ZonedDateTime but it expects datetime instead of time object. I am stuck on how to do this

Comment: Java needs a date because of daylight saving. Otherwise you can do the math yourself, but know that it could be wrong twice a year.

Comment: I am using this for the indonesia region, i.e my code works on a server based in indonesia, So daylight savings is not a problem

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused by exactly what you're looking for, but I think you're looking for the `LocalTime` class. It doesn't store any information about date or timezone. It basically just stores the value as you would see on a clock on the wall. You can add other formats as well such as adding seconds: `"HH:mm:ss"`

```
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String timestamp = "14:00";
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm");
        LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.parse(timestamp, formatter);
        System.out.println("Local Time: " + localTime);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks I meant if it is 12:00 in utc+03:00 what time will it be in my local if my zone is utc+08:00. I wanted that conversion

Answer (score 0):

You can work with classes [OffsetTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetTime.html) and [LocalTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html). Those classes only require time and not date. And you can convert it from `LocalTime` to `OffsetTime` using `OffsetTime` method 
[public static OffsetTime of(LocalTime time, ZoneOffset offset)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetTime.html#of-java.time.LocalTime-java.time.ZoneOffset-)

Comment: Thanks this is what I needed, I ended up using ZonedDateTime.